# Special Price Tax

Tags: magento2, special-price, price-rules

recently i upgraded my Magento2.2.8 to Magento2.3.3 after upgrade i add product in my cart and go to cart page and see summary on cart Page the tax added 10% which is ok but the issue is if i add product which have special price then 10% tax not applying on special price its applying in original price its very Strange.

Product A added in cart
price 405
special price 305

Actual result
after 10% tax applied its showing 40

Expected result 
after applying tax 10% it should be 30
what is the solution?

Comment: There is a setting for this in ```Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Apply Tax On > Special Price if available``` can you check it please?

Comment: no not any option like this

Comment: how can i do programticallt

Comment: Please check same case in Magent 2.3.3 default setup, and if it is working then it might be issue with your custom modules.

Comment: not using acutally when i run  php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0):